# adding rows with data from a Mysql table to jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

Adding the colums works, but i am stuck when i want to add the data of the columns stored in a mysql database to the `jtable`. it ask for a object `vector[][]` but i have no clue what to give

```
Connection con;
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

public Hoofdscherm() {
    initComponents();
    uitvoerSpelers.setModel(model);

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fullhouse", "root", "hamchi50985");

        // selecteer gegevens uit fullhouse.speler tabel
        PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM fullhouse.speler");

        // sla deze GEGEVENS op in een resultset
        ResultSet resultaat = stat.executeQuery();

        // haal alle kolomnamen op PUUR VOOR DE MODEL VAN JTABLE 
        ResultSetMetaData data = resultaat.getMetaData();

        String[] colum = new String[15];
        for (int i = 1; i < data.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            colum[i] = data.getColumnName(i);
            model.addColumn(colum[i]);
            while (resultaat.next()) {
                Object[] gegevens  = new String[] {resultaat.getString(1)};
                model.addRow(gegevens[0]);
            }
        }    
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this.

**Note** 
1. Also add your columns separate to resultset data. Like I showed in my code below.

```
Vector<String> rowOne = new Vector<String>();
rowOne.addElement("R1C1");
rowOne.addElement("R1C2");

Vector<String> rowTwo = new Vector<String>();
rowTwo.addElement("R2C1");
rowTwo.addElement("R2C2");

Vector<String> cols = new Vector<String>();

Vector<Vector> vecRow = new Vector<Vector>();
vecRow.addElement(rowOne);
vecRow.addElement(rowTwo);
cols.addElement("Col1");
cols.addElement("Col2");
JTable table = new JTable(vecRow, cols);
```

**Edit**

For you convenience and requirement You can follow code structure below.

```
 Vector<String> rows = new Vector<String>();
 Vector<Vector> dBdata = new Vector<Vector>();

// Add Columns to table
for (int i = 1; i < data.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    colum[i] = data.getColumnName(i);
    model.addColumn(colum[i]);
}

while (resultaat.next()) {
    // add column data to rows vector
            // Make sure that all data type is in string because of generics
    rows.add(resultaat.getString("columnName1"));
    rows.add(resultaat.getString("columnName2"));
    rows.add(resultaat.getString("columnName3"));

    // add whole row vector to dBdata vector
    dBdata.addElement(rows);
}
model.addRow(dBdata);
```

Vector implements a dynamic array. It is similar to ArrayList, but with two differences:

1. Vector is synchronized.
2. Vector contains many legacy methods that are not part of the collections framework.

[Class Vector Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: but i need to start the loop at 1, because data.getColumnCount returns the first column as 1... doesnt it? what is a vector, though? looks like an arraylist to me

Comment: @hamchi You are right `getColumnCount()` is 1-based not 0-based. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The line `model.addRow(gegevens[0]);`is incorrect.
You should do something like this:

```
   String[] colum = new String[15];
    for (int i = 1; i < data.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        colum[i] = data.getColumnName(i);
        model.addColumn(colum[i]);
        while (resultaat.next()) {
            Object[] gegevens  = new String[] {resultaat.getString(1)};
            model.addRow(gegevens);
        }
    }
```

Also you need to check [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

According to the documentation of DefaultTableModel:

> This is an implementation of TableModel that uses a Vector of Vectors
>   to store the cell value objects.